# Toggle button to hide or unhide the facebook comment box

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to make the toggle button. I taking the data from the database and each confession (container similar to blog) have facebook comment box. I just want to make a button to hide or unhide the facebook comment box, but it not work. I'm attaching the screenshot of my web page.
 [image]

```
<?php
$id="0";
$sql="SELECT * FROM user_confession";
require 'connection.php';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
  {


                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                    {
                                        $date= $row['date1'];
                                        $confession= $row['confession'];
                                        $userid=$row['id'];


echo"<div style='border: 2px solid black;width: 85%;margin-left:55px;overflow: hidden;margin-top: 10px; '>
</div>";

echo"<div id='confession_container'>";
        echo"<div id='date'>";
            echo $date;
        echo"</div>";

    echo"<div  id='confession_content'>
        #confession no'"; echo $id=$id+1;echo"

        <p style='margin-bottom: 10px;'>";echo $confession; echo"</p>";
        $id='confession'.$userid;

        echo" <button onclick='myFunction('confession20')'>Comment</button>";

        echo"<div id='confession20' class='fb-comments' data-href='https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator1' data-numposts='5'></div>


    </div>
</div>";
}
}
?> 




<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId=1554032561304520';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>     

<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction(p1) 
{   
    console.log(p1);
    var x = document.getElementById(p1);
    if (x.style.display === "none") 
    {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: could you ask a question?
would be good to have a coding example with already rendered markup and no PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Working Example for your case [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrVAP/4914/).

Actually what is happening in your case your `fb-root` div does not have style property assigned so when you are trying to get it's `x.style.display` property then it is returning **empty** so your if condition is not matched that way it is always going in else block. So i just assign `style="display:none;"` property to div tag and it is working now.

**First Way**

**HTML**

```
<button id="btnToggle">Toggle Hidw Show</button>
<div id="fb-root" style="display:none;">
  <h2>Zebra</h2>
  <p>Here is a paragraph about zebras.</p>
</div>
```

**javascript Code**

```
document.getElementById("btnToggle").onclick = function() {
  myFunction('fb-root');
}


function myFunction(p1) 
{   
    console.log(p1);
    var x = document.getElementById(p1);
    if (x.style.display === "none") 
    {
        x.style.display = "block"; 
    } 
    else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

**Second Way**

**HTML**

```
<button id="btnToggle">Toggle Hidw Show</button>
<div id="fb-root">
  <h2>Zebra</h2>
  <p>Here is a paragraph about zebras.</p>
</div>
```

**javascript Code**

```
document.getElementById("btnToggle").onclick = function() {
  myFunction('fb-root');
}


function myFunction(p1) 
{   
    console.log(p1);
    var x = document.getElementById(p1);
    if (x.style.display === "none" || x.style.display === "") 
    {
        x.style.display = "block"; 
    } 
    else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#showHideCommentBox").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var divToHideOrShow = $("#myCommentBoxDiv")
            if (divToHideOrShow.css("display") == "none") {
                divToHideOrShow.show();
            }
            else {
                divToHideOrShow.hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showHideCommentBox">Mostrar/Ocultar</button>
```

** #myCommentBoxDiv is the div to hide or show
** #showHideCommentBox is the button

Comment: Don't you think that loading jquery for single feature is little unnecessary?

Comment: there are not only one comment box ,there are more than 20 seprate comment box for each and every confession content and we generate id dynamcaly

Comment: you can try to use the functions .find() and .closest()
See this jsfiddle and tell me 
https://jsfiddle.net/1dcw1cnd/